# Predicting time series with OpenBUGS

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive, bugs

I have a number of fairly short time series (about 4–100 observations) which I need to forecast into the future. I decided to use Bayesian inference, because there is external information about each time series (the time series are mutually similar), and prediction probabilities would be very desired.

I chose to create a Bayesian model resembling the classical AR model:

$$
y_{i+1} = b_0 + b_1 y_i
$$

The prior for $y_i$'s in the future should be a normal distribution derived from all time series.

However, I have a problem combining these two sources of information (from the autoregressive model and prior) together in an OpenBUGS model (via *BRugs*).

This is a fairly simple model implementing only the autoregressive model:

```
model {
    b0 ~ dunif(-20,20)
    b1 ~ dunif(-20,20)
    sd ~ dunif(0, 10)
    tau <- 1/(sd*sd)

    for (i in 2:N) {
        mu[i] <- b0 + b1*y[i-1]
        y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
        z[i] <- y[i]
    }

    for (i in (N+1):(N+K)) {
        mu[i] <- b0 + b1*z[i-1]
        z[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    }
}
```

where `N` is the number of observations, `K` number of predicted values, and `z[(N+K):(N+K)]` are the predicted values. It works pretty well with simple time series such as (1,2,4,8,16), but fails with real time series, as it tends to grow exponentially (it is not stable). I belive that restricting y's  to a normal prior distribution would alleviate the problem, but I do not know how to extend to model to do that. It should be something it the sense of:

```
z[i] ~ dnorm(mu0, tau0)
```

where `mu0` and `tau0` are defined externally, but that would not be possible here, as `z[i]` is already defined. How to construct such a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $AR(1)$ model is stationary if and only if $|b_1|<1$. So, if you know that the predicted time series should be stable, you should incorporate this to the prior: let 
\begin{equation}
b_1 \sim U(-1,1)
\end{equation}
instead of $b_1\sim U(-20,20)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good idea. But I would still prefer a way in which the prior is somehow incorporated as well.

Comment: @peter The prior *is* incorporated with the answer here. You state that you don't want the series to "grow exponentially". For the AR(1) that implies a stationary model and hence you are using that prior information to indicate that you don't know what the value of $b_1$ is but it should be between -1 and 1 To satisfy the stationarity requirement.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I mean the prior being derived from the other times series (external to the problem). It is time series about users, and from looking at all users I know e.g. that values should be between 10 and 30 (expressed as a normal distribution), and I want to use this information when predicting the time series of an individual user. This would be especially useful when predicting users with very short time series. In the extreme case, the time series of a user has zero length, and then the values should be drawn simply from the normal prior.

Comment: Now I see the external prior I mention should probably go into `b0` (instead of `dunif(-20,20)`).

Comment: I think you may be confusing the value of $y_i$ with the AR(1) parameter. The AR(1) parameter ($b_1$) indicates what proportion of the information from $y_{i-1}$ propagates to $y_i$, then you add the constant term ($b_0$). If all the series were centred, then they'd all have mean zero and $b_0$ would be 0 leaving you just the AR(1) parameter plus Gaussian noise. Hence, for series with values between the ones you state, don't you want the wider prior on $b_0$ and leave the AR(1), $b_1$, at the (-1, 1) prior suggested.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes, I think you are right.